# Prove $T$ is diagonalizable and find a basis $B$ of $V$ such that the matrix associated to $T$ be diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=\mathbb{R}^3$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ the linear operator defined by $T(x,y,z)=(3x-z,2x+4y+2z,-x+3z)$

Prove  $T$ is diagonalizable and find a basis $B$ of $V$ such that the matrix associated to $T$ be diagonal.

Let $B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ the canonical basis of $V$
this implies $T_{BB}=\begin{bmatrix}
3 &2  &-1 \\ 
 0&4  &0 \\ 
 1&2  &3 
\end{bmatrix}$ then by definition
$P_T(\lambda)=det(xI-T)=det(xI-T_{BB})=det\begin{bmatrix}
-3+x &-2  &1 \\ 
 0&-4+x  &0 \\ 
 -1&-2  &-3+x 
\end{bmatrix}=-40+34x-10x^2+x^3=(x-4)(x^2-6x+10)$

in consequence, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $(x-4)(x^2-6x+10)$

> Then, $x_1=4$ is an eigenvalue. My question, exists other eigenvalue?

If not, then $T$ is diagonalizable, because we have an unique eigenvalue an that eigenvalue go to produce an unique eigenvector and that vector is linearly independent.

> Find the basis $B$ can be a little difficult to me, can someone help me?

Comment: see my answer, you made mistake

Comment: Since $P_T(x )=(x-4)(x^2-6x+10)$, $T$ is not diagonalizable. So you must have done something wrong in proof.

Answer (score 3):

if a n * n matrix has n different  eigenvalues then it is diagonalizable.
here you have to solve $$det(xI−T)=0$$ for x .
so you have $$ (-4+x)[(-3+x)(-3+x)-1]=0$$ 
$$ (-4+x)(X^2+9-6x-1)=0$$
$$(-4+x)(x^2-6x+8)=0$$
$$x=4,-2,4$$
now you have to find eigenspace, you have to show that T-4I span 2 dimension subspaces.

Comment: please accept the answer if it is make sense. thanks

Comment: i think you have an error in your answer, i think is $(-4+x)(x^2-6x+10)=0$

Comment: @OrlianPrato are you sure? $$(-3 + x)(-3 + x) = (-3 + x)^2 = (-3)^2 + x^2 + 2(-3)x = 9 + x^2 - 6x.$$ Now, we subtract $1$ and multiply by $(-4 + x)$. We don't add $1$ to make $x^2 + 10 - 6x$.

Comment: you made mistake dear, look at your first matrix. the a_31=1 not -1

Comment: your matrix has problem, a_13=a_31=-1

Comment: no, $a_{13}=1$ and $a_{31}=-1$

Comment: no, T(1,0,0)= (3,2,-1)

Comment: oh, true. thanks, i don't see that.

Comment: please accept my answer

Comment: wait a moment i'm review your answer

Comment: Then the characteristic polynomial is $(-4+x)(x-2)(x-4)$ this implies $x_1=4$ and $x_2=2$

Comment: @OrlianPrato I edited my answer, is it obvious?

Comment: Good work, pretty answer.

Answer (score 1):

$4$ is the only real eigenvalue. The remaining two are $3\pm i$.

Regarding the basis for which $T$ is diagonal, think of the set of eigenvctors associated with these eigenvalues.

Hint: After change to basis $V$, $T$ becomes $V^{-1}TV$.

Comment: how can i prove $T$ is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

This is just to elaborate on shere's answer:

Clearly your matrix is wrong. The transformation T is represented as:

$$T_{BB}=\begin{bmatrix}
 3 & 2 & -1 \\ 
 0 & 4 & 0  \\ 
-1 & 2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, this means that the characteristic equation is got by:

$$
det \begin{bmatrix}
 x-3 & -2  & 1  \\ 
 0   & x-4 & 0  \\ 
 1   & -2  & x-3 
\end{bmatrix} = 0
$$

This gives us the equation:

$$x^3-10x^2+32x-32=0$$

$$(x-4)(x^2-6x+8)=0$$

$$(x-4)(x-2)(x-4)=0$$

Therefore, the eigenvalues of $T$ are $4$ and $2$. (shere got it wrong here)

This gives us three linearly independent eigenvectors for $T$:

$$[1\quad 0\quad -1],\; [0\quad 1\quad 0],\; and\; [1\quad -2\quad 1]$$

which together form a basis and thus, $T$ is diagonalizable.